# Different routes for HTTPS vs HTTP traffic?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, https

I'm currently using Amazon Route53 to manage our DNS and have run into a snag.

Our static content is served from AWS S3, however, S3 doesn't support HTTPS with CNAME's. To get around Cross Domain issues, our static content is served via CNAME.

So, I'd like to continue to serve HTTP content via S3, and serve our HTTPS content through our own webserver.

However I'm not sure how I can route HTTP traffic to one domain (s3), and route HTTPS to another domain (a webserver).

Comment: It isn't clear to me what `this` is?  If you want to server HTTPS, setup a server that supports HTTPS.

Comment: I'd like `http://mydomain.com` to point to S3. I'd like `https://mydomain.com` to point to a machine that serves https. Cna I do this via DNS? If not, what is the best way (perf and cost wise) to do this.

Comment: Redirect https?

Comment: Which cross domain issues are you facing? If you're just serving content embedded into a HTML file, you can easily serve content from multiple domains (nothing required, just embed them). If you're loading them via AJAX, then there are alternate methods you can use besides a regular $.post() to get them. Most technologies have a method of enforcing cross-domain exceptions as well.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHenderson We're sending messages back to our server by way of iFrame's and `postMessage()`, and while we can look at other ways do crossdomain, it would be a fairly significant rewrite (especially when attempting to address our browser support matrix). If I could route the traffic upfront, that should (in theory) be a cheaper alternative.

Comment: @Alan - you might be out of luck then. The way we worked around those issues was by using callbacks and instead of posting data, we switched it to GET and embed it in a `<script src="">` tag. When that tag is appended to the body, the script loads just fine and then executes the callback that's returned in the body. I believe you can adjust jQuery's default $.ajax() methods to work this way, but you cannot POST data, which can a pretty serious security hole. But I don't know of any way of AJAX POSTing between domains (which I think you already know, hence the question about CNAMEs for HTTPS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS is only concerned with resolving hostnames to IP, and is not concerned with protocol or port numbers -- this means to directly answer your question; No: you cannot use it to route `https://example.com` to one IP and `http://example.com` to another.

---

There are a couple common ways around this:

- Use a reverse proxy listening on both `http://` and `https://example.com`, such as [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/). This proxy can look at the protocol and even request path, and route to other server(s) appropriately.

  - In addition to making your scenario possible, you also get other benefits: SSL offloading to reduce load on your app server, and the ability to run multiple app servers transparently for either redundancy or scale.
  - Downside: If all your servers are not on the same local network, this is pretty inefficient (and slow) as you're going across the internet twice.
- Use separate subdomains, and have your servers send [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers. There are a ton of resources on how to do this so I won't get into it here.

  - Essentially, you'd have `http://static.example.com` and `https://example.com`. DNS would resolve `static.example.com` to S3, and `example.com` to your other app server.

If your app servers are separated by slow network connections (sounds like they are) then IMHO the only way to go is a DNS-based solution.

Comment: Thanks gregmac. The problem with the DNS based solution is that I'd prefer to have the customer install the script once, and not have to worry about knowing if they'll need SSL support or not. 

I think what I'll end up doing is going the first route, using nginx and varnish to serve both http and https content, and no longer use S3.